# Teamcity CI Pipeline cannot run installed dotnet tool (sonarscanner)

Tags: c#, .net-core, teamcity

I have a CI Build Pipeline in Teamcity (OnPremise) and I want to run the sonarscanner from SonarQube for code analysis. I tried alot including the Teamcity Plugin for SonarQube Runner. But it did not really work so I ended up with the following script.

It installs the dotnet tool "sonarscanner" and also "JetBrains.dotCover.GlobalTool". When I run the script locally in terminal, everything works fine. But when I run the script within the Build-Process in TeamCity it crashes when trying to execute `dotnet.exe sonarscanner begin [..]`

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
16:01:24
  Possible reasons for this include:
16:01:24
    * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
16:01:24
    * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-sonarscanner does not exist.
16:01:24
    * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

I have removed some other unrelevant stuff from the script.

```
[..]
dotnet tool install dotnet-sonarscanner --tool-path $executionPath
dotnet tool install JetBrains.dotCover.GlobalTool --tool-path $executionPath
write-host "tool installation finished"

write-host "Starting restore... "
dotnet.exe restore $absoluteSolutionPath --interactive --force
write-host "Restore done"

write-host "Init Sonar Scanner"
dotnet.exe sonarscanner begin /k:"ProjectKey" /d:sonar.host.url="https://ValidDomain"  /d:sonar.login="ValidLoginKey" /d:sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths=".\dotCover.Output.html"
write-Host "Sonar Scanner initialized"

write-host "Start Build Task"
dotnet.exe build $absoluteSolutionPath
write-host "Build Task completed"
[..]
```

After installation the output says

```
Tool 'dotnet-sonarscanner' (version '5.2.1') was successfully installed.
```

So installation succeed, but execution not?! I also executed the script manually on the build server and it works fine.

Is there anything special within the TeamCity Script Execution I am missing here?

I have also seen the question [Azure DevOps - cannot run installed dotnet tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66154186/azure-devops-cannot-run-installed-dotnet-tool) but TeamCity does not have these YML Configration files and I have absolutely not idea how I could apply *use dotnet* Task neither why it should be necessary because I just want to run a script.

Comment: @user889829 unfortunately not. We have tried some other solutions for code analysis during this evaluation and right now we use codacy. It's not perfect but it covers most of what we were looking for and integration via GitHub Actions was pretty simple.

Comment: I had the same issue, found a fix. Posted it below

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, here is how I fixed it.
My first build step is a dotnet toolchain step. For the command I have custom and for the command line parameters I have

> ```
> "tool update --tool-path ./tools dotnet-sonarscanner"
> ```

This forces the tool to be installed to the ./tools directory.
The next build step is a command line step. I run it as a custom script and the command is

> ./tools/dotnet-sonarscanner begin /k:"%SONAR_PROJECT_KEY%"
> /d:"sonar.host.url=%SONAR_HOST%" /d:sonar.login="%env.SONAR_TOKEN%"
> /o:"%SONAR_ORG%" /d:"sonar.branch.name=%teamcity.build.branch%"
> /d:"sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths=%DOTCOVER_HTML%"

What I found is that for some reason the Agent doesn't have access to the any tool installed so when you install the sonarscanner tool the install command will work but when you try to run it, it can't find the executable. By running the executable manually not through dotnet it will work.

Answer (score -1):

I think that your $executionPath is not in the PATH environment variable, so it cannot find it.

You should be able to run the command without the dotnet sonarscanner, but as $executionPath\dotnet-sonarscanner.exe

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/troubleshoot-usage-issues#installed-net-tool-fails-to-run) under the Local Tools heading.